# How to use variables with an utterance file in botium

Tags: botium-box

I have a botium/dialogflow project that my developer has created using node and not botiumbox. I want to be able to call multiple neighborhoods in multiple ways using variables. For example, I know using a variable in an adaptive card should look something like this:

```
Show me a neighborhood

#me
Show me a neighborhood in $neighborhood

#bot
In $neighborhood, there are [0-9]+ active listings.
```

I was previously using an utterance file with different types of utterances such as:

```
NEIGHBORHOOD_SNAPSHOTS_UTT    
Show me a location in Lawrenceville
Show me a market snapshot in Lawrenceville
What are the market stats in Lawrenceville
Find market snapshot in Lawrenceville
```

And my adaptive card looked something like this:

```
Show me a neighborhood

#me
NEIGHBORHOOD_SNAPSHOTS_UTT

#bot
In Lawrenceville, there are [0-9]+ active listings.
```

In the botium wiki somewhere I saw something similar to this, so I saved it as a file named location.txt in the same folder as my conversations and utterance files

```
       |$neighborhood                    |
 Case1 | Lawrenceville                   |
 Case2 | Midway                          |
 Case3 | Paintsville                     |
 Case4 | River Point                     |
 Case5 | The Fountains                   |
 Case6 | Castlewood                      |
 Case7 | Middlebury                      |
 Case8 | Happy Valley                    |
 Case9 | 20th / Breakwood                |
 Case10| Courtney Ct/Knight Ave          |
```

Now I want to tie them together so that I can query multiple neighborhoods in multiple ways, such as

```
 Show me a neighborhood

 #me  
 NEIGHBORHOOD_SNAPSHOTS_UTT.utterances.txt

 #bot
 In $neighborhood, there are [0-9]+ active listings.
```

Where I take my utterance file and change it from Lawrenceville to:

```
Show me a location in $neighborhood
Show me a market snapshot in $neighborhood
What are the market stats in $neighborhood
Find market snapshot in $neighborhood
```

But my project was not seeming to find the location.txt variable file. How can I make utterances, a variable file, and these adaptive cards work together in my project (not botium box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the test case you are trying to create is fine, and you made a lot of things right, but there are some things missing as well.

1. Scripting Memory files are to be named **location.scriptingmemory.txt** (see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48922633/Composing+in+Text+files))
2. First line of the utterances file is the name it is referenced from convo files (one of your examples is correct, the other is not).
3. When referencing utterances in convo files, don't use any file extension (again one time right, one time wrong).

```
#me  
NEIGHBORHOOD_SNAPSHOTS_UTT
```

4. You have to enabled the scripting memory in Botium it is disabled by default - see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/26411023/Botium+Scripting+Memory)
5. And finally, you want Botium to run the same convo multiple times with changed variables, you have to tell this as well (see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48824412/Scripting+Memory+File))

I prepared a [repl.it](https://repl.it/@FlorianTreml/replit-botium-bindings-julie-2) with a demo.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to copy your repl.it example to mine with some tweaks successfully. Note that I have changed some of the naming structures as the question I put up was an example and I had to think the names through. It is however taking $neighborhood and using it directly as if it weren't a variable, even though my scriptingmemory.txt file matches yours.

Comment: Multiple neighborhoods with varied utterances./MARKETSNAPS_NEIGHBORHOOD_VARIED_UTT-L3/Line 8: Expected bot response (on Line 5: #me - What are the market stats in $neighborhood) "There are no market snaps for that location. Try telling me a different zip code, neighborhood, or city and I'll try to find the info." to match one of "In $neighborhood, there are [0-9]+ active listings. The average listing is priced at \$[0-9]+ and is on the market for [0-9]+ days.,There are [0-9]+ market snaps near your location.,There are [0-9]+ market snaps in $neighborhood"
    ########################

Comment: ASSERTION FAILED in TextMatchAsserter - Expected: "In $neighborhood, there are [0-9]+ active listings. The average listing is priced at \$[0-9]+ and is on the market for [0-9]+ days.,There are [0-9]+ market snaps near your location.,There are [0-9]+ market snaps in $neighborhood"  - Actual: "There are no market snaps for that location. Try telling me a different zip code, neighborhood, or city and I'll try to find the info."
    INPUT: What are the market stats in $neighborhood

Comment: Finally (thank you, this is making a huge difference in my project), what if these utterances can return any of the three possible variables and I don't know which one?

In $neighborhood, there are [0-9]+ active listings. The average listing is priced at \$[0-9]+ and is on the market for [0-9]+ days.
There are [0-9]+ market snaps near your location.
There are [0-9]+ market snaps in $neighborhood

How should I format this? I tried a response utterance file and it hasn't worked as expected

Comment: I think the only thing to change is to set capability SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE to regexp to make this work. I updated the repl.